# Export dask task stream to svg

Tags: python, bokeh, dask, distributed

I am doing data analysis with dask_yarn on company cluster.

Dask is showing dashboard on specified link.
After finishing all the tasks I want to save dask dashboard as svg file.

There is no tool for doing this in toolbar.

How can I save the results as svg?

Answer (score 2):

While it does not appear to be possible to save directly with `get_task_stream`, you can use the `bokeh` figure stored in the task stream object as `ts.figure`:

```py
from dask.distributed import Client, get_task_stream
import time

client = Client()

with get_task_stream(client, plot='save', filename='task_stream.html') as ts:
    futs = client.map(lambda x: time.sleep(x**2), range(5))
    results = client.gather(futs)

from bokeh.io import export_png
# note to use this you will need to install additional modules
# conda install -c conda-forge firefox geckodriver
# or see https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/export.html

export_png(ts.figure, filename="plot.png")
```

There are other ways of exporting the bokeh figures, see [docs](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/export.html).